# Joining streams

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe, cat

You normally can pipeline the operations

```
a | b | c
```

where `b` takes input from `a` and sends it to `c`. It has only one input, generated by a. But what if I want to replace a header in file `b`. I therefore echo a new header (this is `a` operation). Additionally, I `cat b | dd bs=1 skip=header_size` to strip the header from the file. This is `bc` operation. Now I have two outputs, produced by `echo new_header` and `cat`. How do I concatenate them?

Comment: If you do `[c(b)](a)`, then `c(b)` must have a command as output. In which case, my answer is what you need.

Comment: Is `b` a binary file? Or is it a shell script of some sort?

Comment: @muru That is shebang java jar. That is, text header with zip tail.

Comment: This question continues to make no sense. What does a shebang have to do with a java jar? You say `a` outputs the new header, but then piping `a`'s output to the `b|c` command makes no sense - you would want something like `a; b|c` instead. This is an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please post the actual problem instead of an imagined half-solution.

Comment: Also, general programming questions should not be asked on AskUbuntu.

Comment: I do not understand how you ask me for real problem and tell that its components have nothing to do with each other. Shebag means you have a text header and jar means that you have binary tail. But, they have nothing to do with each other and do not represent a real problem. Which realexamp≤realexamp≤real example do you need? I attempted to strip the header in bcbcbc. That command would also take output from aaa to prepend the new header.

Comment: Consider completely rewriting your question with what you're trying to do,  including code examples.  I've read your question and haven't the foggiest idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I also don't understand what your actual use case is. You can mix standard input, files, and process substitutions on the `cat` command line if you wish e.g. `echo "new header" | cat - <(dd if=b bs=1 skip=$header_size)`. A more elegant solution might use a here-document. Again, it would be helpful to give us a complete minimal working example.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, `|cat - <(dd if=b)` is what I was asking for. It seems that cat can somehow merge two inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked "How do I concatenate them?" - and the answer is, quite simply, with `cat`:

```
NAME
       cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output

SYNOPSIS
       cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Concatenate FILE(s), or standard input, to standard output.
```

Note in particular that its inputs can include standard input, not just files. So for example, you can:

1. mix standard input and files

   ```
   echo "new text" | cat - oldfile > newfile
   ```
2. mix standard input and process substitutions

   ```
   echo "new text" | cat - <(some_command oldfile) > newfile
   ```

   for example,

   ```
   echo "new header" | cat - <(dd if=oldfile bs=1 skip=$header_size) > newfile
   ```

Alternatively, you could use a *here document* and embed the command output using *command substitution* - that's probably a better option if your replacement text consists of more than a single line e.g.

```
$ cat > newfile << EOF
new
multi-line
header
$(dd if=oldfile bs=1 skip=$header_size)
EOF
```

Comment: Are you sure that `EOF` spans beyond the `dd` command, embracing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like shell process substitution voodoo you can also use a simple redirection of a command group:

```
{ printf '%s\n' 'header line 1' 'header line 2' ...; tail -c +$(($header_size+1)) old-file.txt; } > new-file.txt
```